# HttpTransportSE.call() takes too much time

Tags: android, soap

I'm developing an app with SOAP API at android phone(2.3.6), it communicates with server through WiFi. Now I'm encountering a big problem: When I call HttpTransportSE.call(), it takes about 10 seconds. But if I switch soapAction's address to another server IP, it works well. I also analysed the log from server, it shows that server response to the client is very quick. Does anyone have any experience?

```
// Code for reference
HttpTransportSE ht = new HttpTransportSE(url);
ht.call(soapAction, envelope);    // This sentence will take about 10 seconds in some cases.
```

Comment: Having an extremely similar problem here, the `HttpTransportSE.call()` method takes approximately 25 secs when the actually web service returns data in less than a second. Would love if someone had any solutions.